# can i mutate video campaign from google ads api?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to change video campaign status from ENABLED to PAUSED through google ads api with php and i'm getting an error message "MUTATE_ACTION_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_CLIENT", is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, video campaigns cannot be mutated in any way. This applies both for the legacy Adwords API as well as the Ads API.

See the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/campaigns/overview#differences_from_the_google_ads_ui) or [one of many messages on the Ads API forum](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/x888yAEOl1w/m/kWCWv6TtBAAJ), for instance.